# What is going on with the 'in' function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Something that recently broke my code is that I naively thought that:

`'+' in ['+','-',...] = true`.

The only problem is that it actually evaluates to false!

Someone please help me understand what is going on here!

Comment: `=` is for assigning values to variables or properties; `==` and `===` are for comparison. Also the `in` operator binds loosely; it's a good idea to parenthesize.

Comment: [`in` is an operator not a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

Comment: You need `Array#includes` to check whether an item is present in an array.

Comment: Also of course "+" is not a property of the array; it's the value of an *element* of the array but that's not what `in` does.

Comment: @Pointy IIRC, the `in` operator in other languages (Python?) actually checks if a value is in an array. So, if coming from there, it seems like a normal assumption to make that the JS `in` works the same way.

Comment: The [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator checks if an object has that property which is not the case. For that you should use [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method.

Funny thing in JS, arrays are objects where each element is stored in a numeric property matching that element position, so `0 in ['+'] == true` and `1 in ['+'] == false`.

Comment: @VLAZ yes I'm sure you're right; knowing language A while learning language B can cause all sorts of problems

Answer (score 2):

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the
>   specified object or its prototype chain.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in